# Macros to loop in certain cells

Tags: excel, vba

I'm copying certain values from Sheet3 to Sheet2 and I have a loop for that, the problem is I'd like to loop only in cells. Basically, if I have values 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. in column D of Sheet2, I want to loop only in column H rows containing number '1'. Here's my code so far.

```
Sub rand_v2()

Dim RNG1 As Range, RNG2 As Range, r As Range, p As Range, d As Collection, N As Long, MLRow As Long, x As Long

Set RNG1 = Sheet3.Range("A2:A500")
MLRow = Sheet2.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


For x = 4 To MLRow
    If Sheet2.Cells(x, 8).Value = vbNullString Then
        Set d = New Collection
        For Each r In RNG1
            If r.Value <> vbNullString And Sheet3.Cells(r.Row, 4).Value = Sheet2.Cells(x, 2).Value And r.Value <> Sheet2.Cells(x - 1, 8).Value And r.Value <> Sheet2.Cells(x - 2, 8).Value And r.Value <> Sheet2.Cells(x - 3, 8).Value Then
                d.Add r
                N = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, d.Count)
                d.Item(N).Copy
                Sheet2.Cells(x, 8).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            End If
        Next r
        Set d = Nothing
    End If

Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you using `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: I'm not using it anymore, I must have forgotten to delete or comment it

Comment: OK, then are you getting an error somewhere? When you step through it, where does the logic break? Is it the `If` statement?

Comment: The logic doesn't break. It just loops on the cells in the 8th column (H) of Sheet2 which are empty. I need this to loop in cells that are empty from the same column, but only while specific values from column D are selected.